# Can a SSL be shared between two domains on the same hosting plan

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, hosting

Can I use the SSL certificate that I bought on GoDaddy on another domain, within the same hosting?

I have for example:

http://domain1.com

http://anotherdomain.com

And have both of this domains above share the SSL I have from GoDaddy which would be located on the same host?

Comment: No, you cant. SSL is only for 1 domain. If you purchase wildcard SSL, then you can install it on your subdomain, but you cant install it on other domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The X.509 certificate is issued for SSL server authentication usually for just one domain (www.example.com + example.com). It won't authenticate "anotherdomain.com".

Unless you purchased an X.509 certificate specifically for those two domains combined, you can't use your certificate for domain1.com with anotherdomain.com. You need to purchase another certificate for anotherdomaincom. And then the technical problem appears - to properly present the certificate to the client in HTTPS in most cases the server must have  dedicated IP - one domain name per IP address.